# Android Studio Speed Up Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I was wondering if there was any way to speed up the Android emulator. The emulator I am currently trying to use is a Pixel API 26 and my computer is a 2009 MacBook Pro with 4 gigabytes running OS X Yosemite.

The emulator has been stuck showing the start up screen (white screen with a big colorful G) for more than 2 days. I tried restarting it but it stayed the same

Comment: Preeeetty sure there's something more serious wrong here than just "the emulator being slow"...

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. What are you trying to run on the emulator? How are you launching it? Have you tried stopping it and restarting it? I can't help, I know very little about android dev, but if you include relevant details there's a greater chance people who do know how to help, will.